Best way to build dynamic query with graphql in sitecore jss with nextjs
I am building search query for search result page like below.
let freeTextQuery = '';

if (keyword) {
    freeTextQuery = `{
        name: "itemcontent_s"
        value: "${keyword.toLowerCase()}"
        operator: CONTAINS
    }`;
}       

let templateQuery = '';
props.fields.FilterTemplates.map((template) => {

    templateQuery += `{
        name: "itemtemplatename_s"
        value: "${template.name}"
        operator: EQ
    }`
});

let pageTemplateQuery = '';

if (templateQuery !== '') {
    pageTemplateQuery = `{
    OR: [
        ${templateQuery}                 
    ]}`;
}

const query = gql`
{
    search(
        first:50
        where: {
            AND: [
                {
                    name: "_path"
                    value: "0000-0000-0000-000-0000000000" 
                    operator: CONTAINS
                }
                ${freeTextQuery ? freeTextQuery : '{}'}
                ${pageTemplateQuery ? pageTemplateQuery : baseTemplateQuery}                      
               
            ]
        }
    ) {
        total
        results {
            name                 
           
        }
    }
}`;

is this the proper way or is there any other way to concatenate dynamic query ?

Hello @Vishal can you please ask same question in Sitecore community slack channel, where you will get more information about it
